# Circles1 with maximum and minimum values

Tags: algebra-precalculus, circles, maxima-minima, tangent-line

I have a question regarding the maximum and minimum values of $y-3x+4$ for which point $(x,y)$ moves along circle $(x-2)^2+y^2=1$.
I can calculate the question but I do not know where to locate the maximum and minimum values on the graph.

Comment: The maximum value is $-2+sqrt10$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approach the problem geometrically:

1. Find the intersections point(s) between line and circle (solve system of equations).
2. If there are two points, the max will occur at the right point (bc line has positive slope).
3. If there is only one intersection, the single intersection point will be the maximum (tangent to circle).

Also, the max value is not $-2+\sqrt{10}$ as you can see in picture.

[image]

Comment: I use $y-3x+4=k$, and $y=3x+k-4....(1)$, and circle is $(x-2)^2+y^2=1.......(2)$.  By using the Quadratic formula I got $k=-2+\sqrt(10) and k=-2-\sqrt(10)$.

Comment: Ok, I assumed $k = 0$.

Comment: I am using a pre-calculus method by considering $y-3x+4=k$ If $k$ varies the line moves in parallel to itself.

Comment: Can you show me where the maximum and minimum values are on the graph? I am a little bit confused.

Comment: Maximum is the largest $y$-value of the two points.

Comment: Thank you very much. These were my points too, but I wanted to confirm. Much appreciated.